# Payment security on Android App

Tags: android, asp.net, ios, security, payment

I am developing an application which helps user can browse and buy books. The client can be Android ,iOS, Mac. The server is Asp.net Web APIs.

I know there are many service for payment. One of these is Authorize.net and I think I will use it. When user pay for a book, he/she will got a unique link to download data from server. I want to prevent other users who has the link ( by some hacking) download data. Not yet, I want to keep user payment information in secure.

I have no experience in security. So, please give some advices to implement this. Thanks.

Comment: Unsure if your question is appropriate for SO. You have to do your own research, try something, and ask a specific question if you get stuck with a specific issue. Your question is too broad - but if you have no experience in security, then you better start with that - you can't expect to handle sensitive financial/payment information of consumers without a background in security.

Comment: Yeah, my question is too broad. I just try to ask about some tips. Should I consider ssl, https, encrypt, GUID,...?